# SQL Subquery: Filter entries that return no rows

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I'm struggling on a SQL-query... I have three tables:

1) jobs

2) paper1

3) paper2

`paper1` and `paper2` have a colum `job_id` where the corresponding job-id is referenced; so the job with the id **123** has a `paper1.job_id` of **123**.

Now I want to see all jobs that have a corresponding `paper1` but no `paper2` (thus: unfinished, since **paper1** and **paper2** are requirements for the job to be fulfilled). My attempt was like this, but it didn't work out correctly:

```
SELECT id 
FROM   jobs 
WHERE  (SELECT id FROM paper1 WHERE (job_id = jobs.id) != 0 LIMIT 1) 
AND    (SELECT id FROM paper2 WHERE (job_id = jobs.id)  = NULL LIMIT 1)
```

Any help is appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Select job_id 
FROM paper1 
WHERE job_id NOT IN (Select job_id from paper2 group by paper2)

GROUP BY job_id;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! This approach is nearly 12(!) times faster than AnatolyS' approach

Answer (score 1):

```
select id 
from jobs 
where exists (select p1.id from paper1 as p1 where p1.job_id = jobs.id)
    and not exists (select p2.id from paper2 as p2 where p2.job_id = jobs.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding i think you want only the jobs which are only in paper1 but not in paper2
if thats the requirement then try the below code

```
select * from jobs where id in (select distinct j1 from 
(select a.job_id as j1,b.job_id as j2 from paper1 a,paper2 b where a.job_id=b.job_id(+)) 
where j2 is null)
```